# Are there any good sites for blogging about programming?

Tags: language-agnostic, blogs

I have a few programming articles I would like to write, but I do not have a site of my own - yet ;).

Is there a site that is specifically geared toward technical / programming topics, with great functionality and style? Or will I have to go with things like wordpress or blogspot?

I would like a site that can track number of views and that has an intuitive commenting system.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is best blogging host for programmers/code formatting?  ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051/what-is-best-blogging-host-for-programmers-code-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other platforms, but you can do a lot of things with a Wordpress installation and the right plugins: there are plugins for analytics (you can use Google's or install something like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/))

The commenting system is the classical one for blogs, and you can add extra things to it with plugins (like the possibility to edit it after submit) - is there something in particular you are looking for?

The style is for you to choose and customize. There are a lot of free themes, and you can change a lot about it.

Wordpress is quite powerful when you own the domain and can control everything, so I think it's worth a try.

Comment: Well, I meant I do not have a domain yet, and don't have time to set something like that up now. I'm looking for an existing hosted platform that I can just register on and blog. Was just wondering if there is a blogging site that focused on programing topics.

Comment: Not sure aboat that, but there is typepad that's a mix between self-hosted and regular.

Answer (score 1):

See http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/ but that is highly specialized

Answer (score 1):

Rox suggested WordPress. I would second that. You don't need your own domain to start a Wordpress blog. Just go to wordpress.com and sign up. You will probably get an address like wordpress.com/. The advantage would be that when you get your own domain, you probably can export all your content and import it in your own wordpress installation on that domain.